# first last element

Tags: xml, xslt

XSLT XML Question.

Looking into a simple transformation. I have simple index xml input. I have to output the the first and last element with a for each chapter. AS shown below. any help will be much appreciated.

Regards JJ

Input

```
<book>
  <page number="1">Chapter01</page> 
  <page number="2">Chapter01</page> 
  <page number="3">Chapter01</page> 
  <page number="4">Chapter01</page> 
  <page number="5">Chapter01</page> 
  <page number="6">Chapter01</page> 
  <page number="7">Chapter02</page> 
  <page number="8">Chapter02</page> 
  <page number="9">Chapter02</page> 
  <page number="10">Chapter02</page> 
  <page number="11">Chapter02</page> 
  <page number="12">Chapter02</page> 
  <page number="13">Chapter03</page> 
  <page number="14">Chapter03</page> 
  <page number="15">Chapter03</page> 
  <page number="16">Chapter03</page> 
  <page number="17">Chapter03</page> 
  <page number="18">Chapter03</page> 
 </book>
```

Output

```
<book>
  <page number="1">Chapter01</page>  
  <page number="6">Chapter01</page> 
  <page number="7">Chapter02</page> 
  <page number="12">Chapter02</page> 
  <page number="13">Chapter03</page> 
  <page number="18">Chapter03</page> 
</book>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Updated to take advantage of a cleaner predicate - thanks to @SeanB.Durkin.*

**I. XSLT 1.0 Solution**

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:key name="kChapters" match="page" use="." />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <book>
      <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="page[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kChapters', .)[1])]" />
    </book>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page">
    <xsl:copy-of select=".|key('kChapters', .)[last()]" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied to the original XML:**

```
<book>
  <page number="1">Chapter01</page>
  <page number="2">Chapter01</page>
  <page number="3">Chapter01</page>
  <page number="4">Chapter01</page>
  <page number="5">Chapter01</page>
  <page number="6">Chapter01</page>
  <page number="7">Chapter02</page>
  <page number="8">Chapter02</page>
  <page number="9">Chapter02</page>
  <page number="10">Chapter02</page>
  <page number="11">Chapter02</page>
  <page number="12">Chapter02</page>
  <page number="13">Chapter03</page>
  <page number="14">Chapter03</page>
  <page number="15">Chapter03</page>
  <page number="16">Chapter03</page>
  <page number="17">Chapter03</page>
  <page number="18">Chapter03</page>
</book>
```

**...the desired result is produced:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book>
  <page number="1">Chapter01</page>
  <page number="6">Chapter01</page>
  <page number="7">Chapter02</page>
  <page number="12">Chapter02</page>
  <page number="13">Chapter03</page>
  <page number="18">Chapter03</page>
</book>
```

**Explanation:**

- Note the proper use of [`Muenchian Grouping`](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to determine the unique `<page>` elements by their value.
- For each unique `<page>` element, two `<page>` elements are copied: the first and last from the group that contains the unique value.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 Solution**

Note that in XSLT 2.0, the solution becomes even simpler.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <book>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="page" group-by=".">
        <xsl:copy-of select=".|current-group()[last()]" />
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </book>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied to the original XML, the same desired result is produced:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book>
  <page number="1">Chapter01</page>
  <page number="6">Chapter01</page>
  <page number="7">Chapter02</page>
  <page number="12">Chapter02</page>
  <page number="13">Chapter03</page>
  <page number="18">Chapter03</page>
</book>
```

**Explanation:**

- The same methodology is applied, but instead of Muenchian Grouping, XSLT 2.0's [`for-each-group`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group) element and `current-group()` instruction are used.

Comment: Nice solution. In the XSLT 1.0 solution, you could further rationalize by combining the predicate for first and last into one predicate like `[position()=1 or position()=last()]`.

Comment: Really pendantic point in relation to the XSLT 2.0 solution: Although in this particular situation the outcome is the same, INMHO xsl:copy-of is probably more semantically appropriate than xsl:sequence.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin, I was wondering about that... I've read all over the place, but I can't seem to find a clear explanation of the difference between `<xsl:sequence>` and `<xsl:copy-of>`. Can you enlighten me?

Comment: For nodes (not atomic values), copy-of makes a copy, but sequence just makes a reference. Generally one would use a sequence to collect references to nodes into a variable, where the relationship between the collected nodes and other nodes matters.

Comment: Here is an example of the difference: http://oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200608/msg00225.html