# first last element variation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

XSLT XML Question.

I have a variation of my previous question. I have to output the the first and last page element of each section. AS shown below. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks JJ.

Input:

```
<root>
  <page number="1" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="2" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="3" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="4" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="5" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="6" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="7" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="8" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="9" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="10" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="11" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="12" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="13" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="14" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="15" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="16" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="17" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="18" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="19" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="20" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="21" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="22" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="23" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="24" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
 </root>
```

Output:

```
 <root>
  <page number="1" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="6" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="7" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="12" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="13" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="18" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="19" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="24" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
 </root>
```

Comment: You should really accept the good answer to your previous question, before asking another one. You accept an answer by clicking on the check mark next to the answer box.

Comment: Also ABach's anwer to your first question perfectly answers this question.

Comment: In future, please specify the XSLT version you are using. When you don't SO answerers might double their effort providing you with both XSLT 1.0 solution and XSLT 2.0 solution.

Comment: Thanks Sean B.Durkin, I apologies for my indiscretions. I will think ahead in the future. Just a newbie, still finding my way around...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k" match="page" use="@section"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="page[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', @section))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page">
    <xsl:copy-of select=". | key('k', @section)[last()]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: See ABach's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114907) . You can combine the two xsl:copy-of instructions into one for a slightly simpler solution.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin, That's true. Fixed.